# How to print the first field which is having the value based on delimeter

Tags: shell-script, awk, cut

File (`myfile.txt`) contains data as follows:

```
abc#ab1=23
nrt#
#clb1aX
amd#322
```

Desired Output:

```
abc
nrt
clb1ax
amd
```

I could do like this,

```
for i in `cat myfile.txt` 
do 
  s1=`echo $i | cut -d'#' -f1`; 
  s2=`echo $i | cut -d'#' -f2`; 
  if [ "$s1" == "" ]; then 
    echo "$s2" 
  else
    echo "$s1"
  fi;
done;
```

But is there anyway to do this without using `for` and `if`, like using `awk` or `sed` or `cut` or something else in single line?

Comment: [Useless and *dangerous* use of backticks.](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks)

Comment: I could *guess* at what your intention is, but could you use some English words to spell it out for clarity? You want to ... hard-code a delimiter of `#`, and if there's nothing before a (presumed existant) `#`, then print what's after it.... until the next `#`?

Comment: Roman's answer worked for me. My input will be having only two fields delimited by one hash. But fields value would be have some other special characters except hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'#' 'NF{ print ($1 != "" ? $1 : $2) }' file
```

The output:

```
abc
nrt
clb1aX
amd
```

Comment: assuming always at least one of `$1` or `$2` were not null. other wise it will cause empty lines  for the input line like `###test`

Comment: @αғsнιη, that's obvious. Looking at the initial OP's algorithm it implies/expects only 2 fields, so the 2 fields are considered

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer

```
sed -i "/^#/ { s/#\(.*\)/\1/; b }
        s/#.*//" myfile.txt
```

It can be joined in one line by adding the `;` after the `}`, but it will be harder to read it like that.

#### Explanation

`sed -i` Keep the changes in the file, do not write them to `stdout`.

`/^#/` - When `sed` is positioned on the line that starts with `#`.

`s/#\(.*\)/\1/` - Replace the first occurence of `#[everything]` with `[everything]`.

`b` - Stop the work on the current line and start working on the next one.
(Prevents `s/#.*//` command to be executed.)

`s/#.*//` - Remove the first occurence of `#[everything]`.
(This will work for all lines, unless the previous `b` command exited early.)

`myfile.txt` File on which `sed` will perform.

Comment: Why it isn't working if I make it to single line?

Comment: You probably needed `;`, I've updated the answer. Same thing applies now, if you want it in 1 line, just add the `;` after `}`.

Comment: this won't work for the line like  `##test`

Comment: I know, it isn't specified in the test that it needs to work with it. That can easily be added.

Comment: You can probably get away with a simpler regex using cut: `sed 's/^#//' myfile.txt |cut -d'#' -f1`

Comment: You are correct, I did it like this to be safe from lines like `#aaa#bbb#ccc`, but then again, it also wasn't specified in the test, so I probably should've ignored it :D

Comment: you could simplify this to something like `sed -e '/^#/ s/.//; t' -e 's/#.*//'` (hopefully syntax is correct non-GNU version) or `sed '/^#/ s/.//; t; s/#.*//'` for GNU version

Answer (score 1):

What if you had no fields with value or it was not just in the second column? then you would need.

```
awk -F'#' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") {print $i; break} }' infile
```

Given below sample:

```
abc#asd=123
nrt#
#clsdX
####
###here
acn#123
```

will give output:

```
abc
nrt
clsdX
here
acn
```

Or using `sed` and `cut`:

```
cut -d'#' -f1 <(sed 's/^#\+//; /^$/d' infile )
```

- The `s/^#\+//` removes the leading hashes `#` (occurred one-or-more times)
- The `/^$/d` removes produced empty line after above where a line was all hashes `#####` or removes empty lines in file if there was any.
- The `cut -d'#' -f1` print the first field `-f1` when fileds delimited by a hash `-d'#'`

Or `sed` only:

```
sed 's/^#\+//; /^$/d; s/^\([^#]*\)#.*/\1/' infile
```

- This `s/^\([^#]*\)#.*/\1/` captures a group of match start from begging of the line for anything until a first hash seen and just print it in result and ignore rest.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` - assuming only single `#` in input as given in sample

```
$ perl -pe 's/[^#]\K#.*|^#//' ip.txt
abc
nrt
clb1aX
amd
```

- `[^#]\K#.*` to delete all characters from first occurrence of `#` if there is a non`#` character preceding it
- `|^#` otherwise, remove `#` from start of line

Same thing with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\([^#]\)#.*\|^#/\1/' ip.txt
abc
nrt
clb1aX
amd
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed

```
sed 's/^#*\([^#]*\).*/\1/' infile
```

If you want to remove lines only with ####

```
sed 's/^#*\([^#]*\).*/\1/;/^$/d' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/^#/,"")sub(/#/," &");print $1}' file

abc
nrt
clb1aX
amd
```